# Bash check if CIDR address is valid

Tags: regex, bash, validation, cidr

I just can't seem to wrap my head around this.
I have a regex that check if a string contains a valid CIDR notation address.

`(((?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?))(?:\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?![.\d])`

This thing works in Perl, PHP, Javascript, and matches `x.x.x.x/8` to `y.y.y.y/32`.

I've tried to change those `\d` to `[[:digit:]]` and to `\\d` Nothing :(

The test script used to test:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: $( basename $0) 123.456.789.0/12"
    exit
fi
REGEX1='(((?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?))(?:\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?![.\d])'
REGEX2='(((?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\\d|1?\\d\\d?)\.){3}(?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\\d|1?\\d\\d?))(?:\\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?![.\\d])'
REGEX3='(((?:25[012345]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|1?[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]?)\\.){3}(?:25[012345]|2[0-4][[:digit:]]|1?[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]?))(?:\\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(?![.[[:digit:]]])'

REGEX=$REGEX3

if [[ $1 =~ $REGEX ]]
then
    echo "$1 OK!"
else
    echo "$1 Not OK! $REGEX"
fi
```

Any ideas to where to go from here?

Updated. Added working script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: $( basename $0) 123.456.789.0/12"
    exit
fi

REGEX='(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9][0-9]?))(\/([8-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))([^0-9.]|$)'

if [[ $1 =~ $REGEX ]]
then
    echo "$1 OK!"
else
    echo "$1 Not OK!"
fi

if echo $1 | grep -Pq $REGEX
then
    echo "grep $1 OK!"
else
    echo "grep $1 Not OK!"
fi
```

Comment: `=~` uses Extended regular expression and not Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).

Comment: If you have GNU grep, you may be able to use the original regular expression with `if echo $1|grep -Pq $REGEX`. If you need to use POSIX regexes then non-capturing groups are not available (`(?:...)`) and neither are lookaheads (`(?!...)`).

Comment: You may use `(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9][0-9]?))(\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))([^0-9.]|$)`

Comment: Thanks guys. Matt Raines solution works with grep. Revo's solution works with both `=~` and grep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest path to success is GNU grep, which also supports PCRE:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if echo "$CIDR" | grep -qP "$REGEX"
then
  echo "$CIDR OK!"
  exit 0
else
  echo "$CIDR NOT OK!"
  exit 1
fi
```

grep's `-q` makes it silent and relies on the exit code to determine success. `-P` is PCRE.

But I should point out that your regex does not fully match that something is a valid CIDR range; rather, you're matching a valid IP address followed by a slash and a number *n* ∈ 1-32. An additional requirement to CIDR ranges is that the *32-n* lower bits of the address are zero, e.g.:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

valid_cidr() {
  CIDR="$1"

  # Parse "a.b.c.d/n" into five separate variables
  IFS="./" read -r ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4 N <<< "$CIDR"

  # Convert IP address from quad notation to integer
  ip=$(($ip1 * 256 ** 3 + $ip2 * 256 ** 2 + $ip3 * 256 + $ip4))

  # Remove upper bits and check that all $N lower bits are 0
  if [ $(($ip % 2**(32-$N))) = 0 ]
  then
    return 0 # CIDR OK!
  else
    return 1 # CIDR NOT OK!
  fi
}
```

Test this with e.g. `127.0.0.0/24`, `127.1.0.0`, `127.1.1.0/24`.

Or more odd ranges: `10.10.10.8/29`, `127.0.0.0/8`, `127.3.0.0/10`, `192.168.248.0/21`.

Comment: I get your point. The input I'm working with are from whois queries, so I assume it's valid CIDR. The final output is: `insert into blacklist.cidrlist(cidr, minip, maxip, minint, maxint, created) values('${CIDR}','${MINIP}','${MAXIP}', inet_aton('${MINIP}'), inet_aton('${MAXIP}'), now());`

Comment: If you don't need to validate the CIDR range, then you probably don't need to validate the IP address either? If you're extracting CIDR ranges from a file stream, consider `grep -Po '(\d+\.){3}\d+/\d+'`. I'm sure it won't contain false positives, and it surely fits better on one line. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simon's solution is elegant. :)

I'm not a big fan of complex regexes to validate things that have meaning which should be interpreted in other ways, so alternatively, if you'd prefer to do this more with string manipulation than with math, I wrote the following function a while back:

```
valid_cidr_network() {
  local ip="${1%/*}"    # strip bits to leave ip address
  local bits="${1#*/}"  # strip ip address to leave bits
  local IFS=.; local -a a=($ip)

  # Sanity checks (only simple regexes)
  [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}$ ]] || return 1
  [[ $bits =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || return 1
  [[ $bits -gt 32 ]] || return 1

  # Create an array of 8-digit binary numbers from 0 to 255
  local -a binary=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
  local binip=""

  # Test and append values of quads
  for quad in {0..3}; do
    [[ "${a[$quad]}" -gt 255 ]] && return 1
    printf -v binip '%s%s' "$binip" "${binary[${a[$quad]}]}"
  done

  # Fail if any bits are set in the host portion
  [[ ${binip:$bits} = *1* ]] && return 1

  return 0
}
```

This function assembles an IP address in binary, then fails if any "1"s are set in the host portion of the IP address.

Comment: Excellent.  I like that I can adapt this to log out exactly what was wrong with a CIDR input.

Comment: Excellent alternative! I feel like noting that this solution is bash-specific while my solution above is POSIX sh. Not that it makes a big difference, but it is worth noting since there are no `#!...` lines in either answers, and so the reader may get unexpected errors. That is, for @ghoti's answer, use `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/bash`, or `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`, depending on your operating system, and for my solution, use either that or `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm just starting scripting for the first time and want to understand everything. It is certainly not the most elegant and shortest way but so I understand every step as a network guy and I'm able to enable debugging at each step.

```
#!/bin/bash
function checkCidrFormat {
  local ipCidr="${1}"
  local validIpCidr
  validIpCidr='(^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-2]))$'
  if [[ $ipCidr =~ ^$validIpCidr ]]; then
    echo "valid format"
    return 0
  else
    echo "not valid format"
    return 1
  fi
}

function checkCidrValid {
  local ip
  ip=${1%/*}
  local netBits
  netBits=${1#*/}

  #split IP to octets
  local oct1
  oct1=$(echo "${ip}" | tr "." " " | awk '{ print $1 }')
  local oct2
  oct2=$(echo "${ip}" | tr "." " " | awk '{ print $2 }')
  local oct3
  oct3=$(echo "${ip}" | tr "." " " | awk '{ print $3 }')
  local oct4
  oct4=$(echo "${ip}" | tr "." " " | awk '{ print $4 }')

  #convert octets to binary
  local binOct1
  binOct1=$(echo "obase=2;$oct1" | bc)
  local binOct2
  binOct2=$(echo "obase=2;$oct2" | bc)
  local binOct3
  binOct3=$(echo "obase=2;$oct3" | bc)
  local binOct4
  binOct4=$(echo "obase=2;$oct4" | bc)
  #fill leading zeros
  binOct1=$(printf "%08d\n" "$binOct1")
  binOct2=$(printf "%08d\n" "$binOct2")
  binOct3=$(printf "%08d\n" "$binOct3")
  binOct4=$(printf "%08d\n" "$binOct4")

  #concat all binary octets
  local binIp
  binIp="${binOct1}${binOct2}${binOct3}${binOct4}"

  #create binary mask - fill net bits
  local binMask
  for (( c=1; c<="${netBits}"; c++ ))
  do
    binMask+=1
  done

  #create binary mask - fill host bits
  local hostBits
  hostBits=$((32 - "${netBits}"))
  for (( c=1; c<="${hostBits}"; c++ ))
  do
    binMask+=0
  done

  #show host bits from ip vs host bits from mask
  local hostBitsIp
  hostBitsIp="${binIp: -${hostBits}}"
  local hostBitsMask
  hostBitsMask="${binMask: -${hostBits}}"

  #check if given ip was a valid network id, a broadcast or host
  if [[ "${hostBitsIp}" =~ ^[1]+$ ]]; then
    echo "its a broadcast address!"
    return 1
  elif [[ "${hostBitsIp}" =~ ^[0]+$ ]]; then
    echo "its a valid network id for this cidr!"
    return 0
  else
    echo "its a host ip!"
    return 1
  fi
}

while true;
do
read -rp "ip cidr (eg. 172.16.16.32/27): " cidr
if checkCidrFormat "${cidr}"; then
  checkCidrValid "${cidr}"
fi
done
```